Why aren't iOS notifications working for my flutter app yet Android notifications do?
I have followed the exact steps listed here in this guide: https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/firebase-fcm-flutter#0
I believe this may be an official guide provided by firebase themselves. The guide does work when attempting to send a notification to an Android device, but i'm not getting anything for an IOS device. When attempting to use the server sample code provided (to send the notification) but to send a notification to an IOS simulator, i am initially getting "com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingException: Request contains an invalid argument." Then on subsequent runs of the server code i'll get "com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingException: Requested entity was not found."
Yes I have added the APN auth key to firebase and added the key id and team id.
There seems to be little information i'm seeing online about this. I'm really trying to stay within flutter and not have to use swift/objective-c solutions unless i have to. If anyone could provide help regarding this, it would be great.
I have followed the provided guide closely, and though it does work for Android devices, I am not seeing it work for iOS.
I have tried manually adding the GoogleService_Info.plist but that seemed to break it. Seems it's already generated/added, since running the project after adding it will lead to a failed build.
I have also reviewed many of the other similar questions/answers but they are not working for me.

ios simulator doesn't work for testing notfications, also when using firebase cli you should be use ios and android at the same time.

Did you create .p8 file ?

@RamGupta is correct. It seems the simulator will not work. I was able to plug an older ios device and it was able to receive the notification. It was not working on my newer current device but that's because I was using an older version of xcode on an older macbook. Thanks a lot!
